STAN code: indization and variable declaration
I’m trying to move from JAGS to STAN but I don’t get variable declaration and indexed for looping.
I have some data that I want to model in STAN with a beta distribution. The rationale of the task is as follows:
N participants produce T estimations. These estimations are drawn from a beta distribution with parameters a and b that are fixed for each individual participant.
Thus, mi data look like this:
ID Trial  Response
1   1     1 0.9771303
2   1     2 0.7455432
3   1     3 0.7949766
4   1     4 0.0490466
5   1     5 0.1096347
6   2     1 0.6766598
7   2     2 0.4160906
8   2     3 0.5342134
9   2     4 0.5437952
10  2     5 0.5560163
11  3     1 0.4378267
12  3     2 0.3561471
13  3     3 0.4455051
14  3     4 0.5324450
15  3     5 0.7438497
You can simulate this:
    a <- c(1, 6, 3)
    b <- c(1, 4, 5)
    data.frame(ID = rep(c(1, 2, 3), each = 5), Trial = rep(1:5), Response = c(rbeta(5, a[1], b[1]), rbeta(5, a[2], b[2]), rbeta(5, a[3], b[3])))

Now, my STAN code is supposed to take the responses from each trial and participant to estimate the underlying parameters of the beta distribution, a and b, which vary between individuals.
In JAGS, I would do a nested loop, something like:`
    for(i in 1:N) {
        for(j in 1:trials) {
            y[i,j] ~ dbeta(a[i], b[i])
    }
    }

But, how would you specify a model like this in STAN? My code isn’t working but I don’t know if the problem is with the parameter definition, the data structure… It should be easy.

Can you post the code for your entire Stan model?  The R code that you use to fit the model (and the specific format of the data you feed into it) too.
